# Update an entire JFrame, including all JComponents

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm trying to update a `JFrame`, and all of the components in the frame, including `JPanel`, `JLabel` components, etc. I tried using `revalidate()`, but that didn't seem to be working. I have a `JLabel` in the frame displaying an int, and I have the int iterating by 1 when I click a `JButton`. I can see that the value of the int changes, but the actual text on the label doesn't change. I know I can use `JLabel.setText()`, but is there a method to use for all components, that would update the displayed text/image upon pressing a button?

Here is my code below:

```
package repainttest;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Window extends JFrame {
    int test = 1;
    JLabel label;

public Window() {
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    label = new JLabel(Integer.toString(test));
    add(label);

    JButton button = new JButton("Add");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          test +=1;
            System.out.println(test);
            refresh();
        }
    });
    add(button);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public void refresh() {
    SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(this);
    revalidate();
    repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: *".. is there a method to use for all components, that would update the displayed text/image upon pressing a button?"* No, there isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not set the new text (`test`) on the `JLabel`, it is never going to know that the value of `test` is changing. So, please insert following statement:

`label.setText(String.valueOf(test));`

in `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` after following statement:

`test +=1;`

and see the results.